# Your device isnt compatible with this version - shows on all device

Tags: android

I recently uploaded my game on play store. The game works fine in my mobile. but i tried to install it in my friends(3-4) mobile phones it gives below error.
Your device isnt compatible with this version
Here is my android manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-8853085470060311~2582555526"/>
    <service
        android:name="com.ak.fulligola.MusicService"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.ak.fulligola.HomePage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.ak.fulligola.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.ak.fulligola.CharacterSelection" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Below is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ak.fulligola"
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'
}
```

Please help to solve.
Also i have ads in my game. so do i need to provide internet permission.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application supports only Android Pie (9) and Android Q(10) only.
To support vast number of devices, please change minSdkVersion to 23 and update target version to latest available i.e. 30.

Yes, Internet permission is required to show the Ads.